# Как вывести строку так, чтобы показывались символы переноса строк и табуляции

Tags: golang

Т.е. у меня например есть строка

"___Привет мир
и стэковерфлоу"

а вывелось "\tПривет мир\nи стэковерфлоу"

Comment: Если ответ вас устраивает, проголосуйте за него и отметьте его как верный, нажав галочку рядом с ответом. Если нет -- опишите почему.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте аргумент [`%q`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing):

```golang
func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%q", `  Hello, 
playground`)
}
```

Выведет:

```
"\tHello, \nplayground"
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/lfYGLtK9YOY.